# Extraction of date occurrences for multiple names

Tags: r, date, dataframe, extract

I am trying to extract information from this spreadsheet (see example file). I have multiple sheets like this with. I need to record the name and each date that an event (H, HI etc) occurs. I am putting together a master data-set (resembling that shown in final file). With each date listed along with name and the letter code (modality).

I have been trying to use the split function. but it is providing me with lists which isn't helping.

Thanks,
Jordan

**Example data**

```
Feb-15                                                                                                              
NAME    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
Name 1      H       H       H           H       H       HI          H       H       H           H       H       H   
Name 2      H       H   H       H       H   H       H       H       H   H   C   H       H       H   H       H       H
Name 3      H   H   H   H   H   H       H   H   H   H   H   H       H   H   H   H   H   H       H   H   H   H   H   H
Name 4      H   H   H       H   H       H   H   H       H   H       H   H   H   H       H       H   H   H       H   H
Name 5          H           H   H           H       H       H           H       H       H           H       H       H
Name 6              HA  HA  HA  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI
Name 7                                                  C                                                           
Name 8                      C                                                                                       
Name 9                                                                                                          HA  HA
Name 10     HI  HI  HI  HI  HI          HI  HI
```

**Desired Final Outcome**

```
name    date    modality
Name 1  2-Feb-15    H
Name 1  4-Feb-15    H
Name 1  6-Feb-15    H
Name 1  9-Feb-15    H
Name 1  11-Feb-15   H
Name 1  13-Feb-15   HI
Name 1  16-Feb-15   H
Name 1  18-Feb-15   H
Name 1  20-Feb-15   H
Name 1  23-Feb-15   H
Name 1  25-Feb-15   H
Name 1  27-Feb-15   H
Name 2  2-Feb-15    H
Name 2  4-Feb-15    H
Name 2  5-Feb-15    H
Name 2  7-Feb-15    H
Name 2  9-Feb-15    H
Name 2  10-Feb-15   H
Name 2  12-Feb-15   H
Name 2  14-Feb-15   H
Name 2  16-Feb-15   H
Name 2  17-Feb-15   H
Name 2  18-Feb-15   C
Name 2  19-Feb-15   H
Name 2  21-Feb-15   H
Name 2  23-Feb-15   H
Name 2  24-Feb-15   H
Name 2  26-Feb-15   H
Name 2  28-Feb-15   H
```

**Desired outcome just shows first 2 names and all the dates occured, need this done for all**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to solve the common problem of converting your data from [wide form to long form](https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/basics/wide-and-long/). This can be done with the `gather` function from the `tidyr` package (part of the tidyverse).

Here's one way to use it with your data, along with some extra calls from the `dplyr` package to help format it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text="
NAME     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
Name.1   NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  HI  NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   NA 
Name.2   NA  H   NA  H   H   NA  H   NA  H   H   NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   H   C   H   NA  H   NA  H   H   NA  H   NA  H
Name.3   NA  H   H   H   H   H   H   NA  H   H   H   H   H   H   NA  H   H   H   H   H   H   NA  H   H   H   H   H   H
Name.4   NA  H   H   H   NA  H   H   NA  H   H   H   NA  H   H   NA  H   H   H   H   NA  H   NA  H   H   H   NA  H   H
Name.5   NA  NA  H   NA  NA  H   H   NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  H   NA  NA  H   NA  H   NA  H
Name.6   NA  NA  NA  HA  HA  HA  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI
Name.7   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  C   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
Name.8   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  C   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
Name.9   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  HA  HA
Name.10  NA  HI  HI  HI  HI  HI  NA  NA  HI  HI  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA", header = T)

mon.yr <- "Feb-15"

df <- gather(df, key = "date", value = "modality", 2:ncol(df)) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(modality)) %>% 
      mutate(date = sub('X(\\d+)', paste0('\\1-', mon.yr), date)) %>% 
      arrange(NAME)
```

After running this we have:

```
> head(df)
    NAME      date modality
1 Name.1  2-Feb-15        H
2 Name.1  4-Feb-15        H
3 Name.1  6-Feb-15        H
4 Name.1  9-Feb-15        H
5 Name.1 11-Feb-15        H
6 Name.1 13-Feb-15       HI
```

Comment: Thank you @C. Braun. I knew there was a package that I could you, just didn't know how to phrase question for google.

Comment: I just ran the code through R. It works till %>% (Error in gather(df, key = "date", value = "modality", 2:ncol(df)) %>% : could not find function "%>%")

Comment: Bypassed this previous error. Now I have this error ---                       
                                                                                                       
Error in filter(., !is.na(modality)) : object 'modality' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you're getting that. Maybe make sure you're using the correct `gather` and `filter` by explicitly mentioning where they come from. So does it still happen if you replace `gather` with `tidyr::gather` and `filter` with `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: Got it :) The dplyr package wasn't loaded properly. Many thanks.

Comment: Great! If that works, would you mind marking the answer as resolved?